# "clear" comand throws some junk values before clearing the screen

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, fedora

I recently noticed that the `clear` command in ***Fedora 19*** throws some junk value before actually clearing the screen Here's a sample output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# clear
[3;J










[root@localhost ~]#
```

Here's a screenshot of this:

[image: clear command]

[Clear](http://linux.die.net/man/1/clear) doesn't throw much light on this and neither does the man page. This issue was replicated on ***CentOS 7*** too. Any explanation on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All problems with output to terminal usually heavily linked to terminal settings. TERM environment variable should match actual terminal. Clear perform a lot of thing with terminal (like resetting a tabstops of locked areas, and exact op list is depends on settings).

- For linux (text/framebuffer) - TERM=linux
- For most of grafical terminal (like xterm, gnome-terminal, xfce4-terminal) TERM=xterm
- For screen TERM=screen

One more: if someone mess up with your terminal settings, clear may be not enough. Use 'stty sane' command.

One more reason for junk after command: it can be bash prompt. Compare clear with 'echo -n' output. If same junk has appeared after echo, that is PS1, PS2, PS3, PS4 prompts.